# How to compare two Pandas DataFrames on values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two Pandas DataFrames (`A` & `B`) with latitude and longitude.

I need to compare them, and if latitude and longitude from `DF A` is present in `DF B` then append a `1` else `0`.

```
DF A

 LatLong
-37.3794288,175.6697856
-37.0334148,174.8680204
-41.173852,174.981931

DF B
KBATMLongLat
-37.0334148,174.8680204
-37.5575605,175.1584622
-37.0334148,174.8680204
```

How can I achieve the expected output (see below)?

```
 Long lat               | Result
--------------------------------
-37.3794288,175.6697856 | False
-37.0334148,174.8680204 | True
-41.173852,174.981931   | False
```

Comment: I see result should be `False, True, False` ?

Comment: That is what the result should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame([[-37.3794288,175.6697856],
                    [-37.0334148,174.8680204],
                    [-41.173852,174.981931]],
                   columns=['Long', 'Lat'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame([[-37.0334148,174.8680204],
                    [-37.5575605,175.1584622],
                    [-37.0334148,174.8680204]],
                   columns=['Long', 'Lat'])


df1['Result'] = [tuple(i) in set(map(tuple, df2.values)) for i in df1.values]

#         Long         Lat  Result
# 0 -37.379429  175.669786   False
# 1 -37.033415  174.868020    True
# 2 -41.173852  174.981931   False
```

Alternatively, more pandonic:

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, indicator=True, how='left').\
              drop_duplicates().rename(columns={'_merge': 'Result'})

df['Result'] = df['Result'].map({'left_only': False, 'both': True})
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me (the first answer is what I used) `KBdf['Result'] = [tuple(i) in set(map(tuple, KBATMdf['column'].values)) for i in KBdf['column'].values]`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how efficient this is, but you could use a multi-index

```
df1 = df1.set_index(["Long","Lat"])
df2 = df2.set_index(["Long","Lat"])
df1["Result"] = df1.index.isin(df2.index)
df1 = df1.reset_index()
df1


    Long        Lat         Result
0   -37.379429  175.669786  False
1   -37.033415  174.868020  True
2   -41.173852  174.981931  False
```